# GWT ActivityManager with Panels

Tags: gwt, android-activity, panel

How come an ActivityManager can only be used with one widget and not a Panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActivityManager` can be used with anything that implements `AcceptsOneWidget` interface. Most commonly used is `SimplePanel`. Inside it you can put any type of panel or widget.